# how to give two or more than two values to a CSV cell in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I have created a csv file and added headers to the file and i am also giving the values to the headers. How can i give 2 values to one header, Suppose in the code written below. is it possible if "column3" can have two values 3 and 4 and in CSV file if could actually see a column containing 2 values ?

```
Headers_of_csv = ["Column1","Column2","Column2"]
csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(mycsv,fieldnames=Headers_of_csv)
  csv_writer.writeheader()
  csv_writer.writerow({"Column1":1,"Column2":2,"Coulmn3":(3,4,5,6)})
                                            #is it possible to assign multiple values here
```

CSV Representation:

```
        |Column1|   Column2|  Coulmn3|
Row1    |   1    |   2      |    3    |
        |        |          |    4    |
        |        |          |    5    |
        |        |          |    6    |
_ _ _ _ | _ _ _  |_ _ _ _ _ |_ _ _ _ _|_
Row2       X        X         X
```

is it possible to assign 2 values to coulmn 3 ?

Comment: Do you mean you actually want two values in column 3 (I don't know what that would mean) or just a single value with a comma in it? For the latter, did you try just passing in a string?  `{"Column1":1,"Column2":2,"Coulmn3":"3,4"}`

Comment: yes i want two values in "column3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is just text separated by separators (usually commas). You just need to define a format that can contain two values in the same cell, for example

```
1,2,3::4
```

Python

```
csv_writer.writerow({
    "Column1": 1,
    "Column2": 2,
    "Column3": "%d::%d" % (3,4)
})
```

**Updated:**

You can as well use `str.join`

```
csv_writer.writerow({
    "Column1": "::".join(map(str, [1])),
    "Column2": "::".join(map(str, [2])),
    "Column3": "::".join(map(str, [3, 4]))
})
```

Comment: my data is being calculated and it varies, i need more than 2 value in one column, What if i need 10 values in one column, Assigned values to the column are being calculated at run time

Comment: your answer solves my half problem, But the value of "Column3" depends upon the data that i am fetching from different file. Suppose if i want 10 values for "Column3" for second row  , how will i do it ?

Comment: the values of column 3 is a list of values, right? Doesn't `str.join(list)` solve your problem? It doesn't matter how many values you have in column 3

Comment: right, value of columns is a list of values. Let me try str.join(list)

Comment: `str.join` expects a list of strings. I updated the answer.

Comment: `"::".join(map(str, [1]))`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it gives me invalid syntax error...When i did "Column3": "::".join(str(map(str,[1]))

Comment: @QuanTo syntax error... copied your solution but did not work

Comment: That's quite generic. Did you check your indentation? Are you using tabs? Codes copied from the internet usually use 4 spaces for indentation.

Comment: @QuanTo csv_writer.writerow({"File Name":values[0],"Status of ATP":values[1],"Number Of Passes":values[2],"Number of Failures":values[3],"Total Tests":"::".join(str map(str,value[1])),"Errors":values[5],"Run Date":values[6]})
                                                                                                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `"Total Tests":"::".join(str map(str,value[1]))` This is the syntax error. It should be `"Total Tests":"::".join(map(str, value[1]))`